# Preventing the page access for unauthorized users

Tags: authentication, yii2

I thought i have made a successful login system using this code in controller:

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/telephone/index'); 
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/telephone/add');   
        }
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

but i then realize anybody could access `/telephone/add` without logging in going directly to the url. How  can i prevent access to that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  configuring properly the behavior  in related controller

```
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * Site controller
 */
class YourTelephoneController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    .......
                    [
                        'actions' => ['add', ],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                    ........
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
...
```

see these link for more  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-filters.html#access-control

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-filters.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-actionfilter.html

Comment: thanks. but it is redirecting to site/login instead i want telephone/login for unauthorized users.